# ApolloGraphQL keeps displaying errors in console

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I have the following mutation:

```
const [CreateDoc, {error, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_DOC, {
    onError(err) {
              setErrorMsg([...msg_error]);
            }
}
CreateDoc({ variables: { input } });
```

Although I have an onError defined in the mutation, I keep seeing the error 400 (bad request) in the console. How can I capture that error in a way that doesn't show in the browser's console?

Thanks

Comment: Your `CREATE_DOC` mutation has a syntax error OR includes an invalid mutation name OR invalid parameters OR is attempting to return something it can't. Try the same mutation from GraphiQL or Apollo-Studio to ascertain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `variables` in `useMutation` hook